# Generating Web Client from local WSDL File using wsimport

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsimport, java-ws

I am using the command:

wsimport -keep

I fails to parse the file because it is trying to find the schema file locally. Is there a way of downloading the schema files or making the parser access the files remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Disable settings and try the commands below

On command prompt, enter following command at it will show the usage of this utility:

```
$wsimport
```

Now, let’s take the WSDL file that was saved in step 1.4, browse to the saved directory using command prompt, and execute the following command:

```
$ wsimport -keep -p client calculator.wsdl
```

Alternatively, we can also specify the URL of WSDL file in the wsimport command:

```
$ wsimport -keep -p client http://127.0.0.1:10000/calcServer?wsdl
```

Comment: what if it needs authentication with special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

wsimport  ***WSDL URL***   -s  ***destination folder***